# Display Listbox with columns using Tkinter?

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I'm trying to create a `Listbox` in Tkinter that has columns.

I'm returning from a DB query records and would like to display each entry in it's own column for each record.

Looking at `Listbox`, I feel like there should be this functionality there but can't find it. What widget should I be using to do this? I've been searching around online but documentation has been very sparse.

Comment: The basic Tk ListBox isn't multi-column. So you need to find one of the various multi-column listboxes, like TkTreectrl, ttk::treeview or one of the many others. TkTreeCtrl is the most powerful and versatile of those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [TkTreectrl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkintertreectrl/files/):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import TkTreectrl as treectrl
import sqlite3

def setup_table(connection):
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE foo
                      (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                      bar TEXT)''')
    sql='INSERT INTO foo (bar) values (?)'
    for i in range(10):
        cursor.execute(sql,(i,))
    cursor.execute(sql,(u'\N{INFINITY}',))

def select_cmd(selected):
    print 'Selected items:', selected

def main():
    connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')   
    setup_table(connection)
    cursor=connection.cursor()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Simple MultiListbox demo')
    mlb = treectrl.MultiListbox(root)
    mlb.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    tk.Button(root, text='Close', command=root.quit).pack(side='top', pady=5)
    mlb.focus_set()   
    mlb.configure(selectcmd=select_cmd, selectmode='extended')
    mlb.config(columns=('Column 1', 'Column 2'))
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from foo')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        mlb.insert('end',*map(unicode,row))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: How to install TkTreectrl in Windows 10?

Comment: To install there are instructions on the somewhat baffling homepage http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 36):

You can use Ttk/Tkinker [`Treeview`](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget, which is used to work with tabular data.

The following is an [example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/350266/creating-table-in-python) of a class that uses a `Treeview` widget to display a multi-column list of strings:

```
'''
Here the TreeView widget is configured as a multi-column listbox
with adjustable column width and column-header-click sorting.
'''
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont
    import ttk
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MultiColumnListbox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()

    def _setup_widgets(self):
        s = """\click on header to sort by that column
to change width of column drag boundary
        """
        msg = ttk.Label(wraplength="4i", justify="left", anchor="n",
            padding=(10, 2, 10, 6), text=s)
        msg.pack(fill='x')
        container = ttk.Frame()
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
            command=self.tree.yview)
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
            command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
            xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)

def sortby(tree, col, descending):
    """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
    # grab values to sort
    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    # if the data to be sorted is numeric change to float
    #data =  change_numeric(data)
    # now sort the data in place
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \
        int(not descending)))

# the test data ...

car_header = ['car', 'repair']
car_list = [
('Hyundai', 'brakes') ,
('Honda', 'light') ,
('Lexus', 'battery') ,
('Benz', 'wiper') ,
('Ford', 'tire') ,
('Chevy', 'air') ,
('Chrysler', 'piston') ,
('Toyota', 'brake pedal') ,
('BMW', 'seat')
]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Multicolumn Treeview/Listbox")
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

These are some pictures of the result of using a `Treeview` widget:

[image]

Comment: I try to improve as many as possible questions and answers on `tkinter/ttk` in order to give a good reference on those toolkits to other people. I think tkinter deserves a better support, mostly in terms of forums. No real dedicated forum around the web on tkinter/ttk.

Comment: Is it possible to update this view? For example new records are inserted to a database table? @NafisAhmad

Comment: Yes, it is possible. 

Just add a button, which will change array vales car_list. as far as i can remember, the table automatically updates when you change the data.

Sorry, i could not run my own code, so i am could not give you a running example.

Answer (score 9):

One simple solution is to use two listboxes side-by-side. There's no real magic, you just have to do a little bit of extra work to get one scrollbar to control both (easily done) and have the selection in the two sync up (also easily done).

Comment: Some sort of example of this capability would be a fine addition