# How to imitate this table using Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[image]

How to get started with creating a similar table using Tkinter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display ListBox with Columns using Tkinter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286093/display-listbox-with-columns-using-tkinter)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the Ttk/Tkinter [Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget. This provides either a *tree-style* layout or a *listview* style columns with headings layout.

As the `Treeview` widget is from Tk's themed icon set it will look appropriate on Windows - picking up the current border and column heading styles so that the look should match the current example posted.

Example (that will work in both Python 2 & 3):

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
    from ttk import *
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *


class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateUI()
        self.LoadTable()
        self.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def CreateUI(self):
        tv = Treeview(self)
        tv['columns'] = ('starttime', 'endtime', 'status')
        tv.heading("#0", text='Sources', anchor='w')
        tv.column("#0", anchor="w")
        tv.heading('starttime', text='Start Time')
        tv.column('starttime', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.heading('endtime', text='End Time')
        tv.column('endtime', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.heading('status', text='Status')
        tv.column('status', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
        self.treeview = tv
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def LoadTable(self):
        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="First", values=('10:00',
                             '10:10', 'Ok'))

def main():
    root = Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This should yield something like this on Windows:

[image: treeview demo]

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an array of ext entries, and lay then out with the "grid" layout manager in a parent frame.

Developing a Python's class to allow managing the grid and cell contents as a single table,
implementing things like `__getindex__` to get cell contents, and even some bits of reactive programing, allowing certain cols to change with values changing elsewhere would be the fun part in such a project.

To create the grid, it is just a matter of:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
frame = Tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

entries = {} # this 'entries'is what you might want to specify a custom class to manage
             # for now,a dictionary will do

for j in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        e = tkinter.Entry(f)
        e.grid(column=i,row=j, borderwidth=0)
        es[i,j] = e
```

And there you are.

Comment: What is `f` in the `Entry`? And es == entries??

Answer (score -2):

def karra_table(n):
for i in range(1, 11):
for j in range(1, n+1):
print(f'{j:2d}  * {i:2d} = {i*j:2d}', end='\t')
print()

karra_table(int(input('Enter n: ')))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).