# How can I get rid of the ], [ and ' signs in a printed table in ttk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

This question is related to: [How to imitate this table using Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456445/how-to-imitate-this-table-using-tkinter).

I have tried the first example, but I get in the printed table the borders `[`, `]` of the arrays and the `'` signs of the strings. How can I get rid of them?

Below is the source code, based on the previous example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 10 14:26:37 2016

@author: peterk
"""

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import * 
import numpy as np
class App(Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateUI()
        self.LoadTable()
        self.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def CreateUI(self):
        tv = Treeview(self)
        tv['columns'] = ('Parameter A', 'Parameter m', 'Parameter n')
        tv.heading("#0", text='Based on fit', anchor='w')
        tv.column("#0", anchor="w")
        tv.heading('Parameter A', text='Parameter A')
        tv.column('Parameter A', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.heading('Parameter m', text='Parameter m')
        tv.column('Parameter m', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.heading('Parameter n', text='Parameter n')
        tv.column('Parameter n', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
        self.treeview = tv
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def LoadTable(self):
        table1=np.reshape(np.array([10.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.,13.,14.,15.,16.,17.,18.]), (6,3))
#        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="First", values=('10:00',
 #                           '10:10', 'Ok'))

        table2 = numpy.array(["%.8e" % w for w in table1.reshape(table1.size)])
        table2 = table2.reshape(table1.shape)
        print(table2)

        for i in range(6):
           self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="based_on_line_"+str(i), values=(table2[i,:]))                     

def main():
    root = Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your numpy array `table2` is of type string:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> table1=np.reshape(np.array([10.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.,13.,14.,15.,16.,17.,18.]), (6,3))
>>> table2 = np.array(["%.8e" % w for w in table1.reshape(table1.size)])
>>> table2.dtype
dtype('S14')
>>>
```

And in your `LoadTable()` method, you are inserting strings:

```
self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="based_on_line_"+str(i), values=(table2[i,:]))
```

So it is normal to have that result as table2 is a mere table of strings:

```
>>> table2
array(['1.00000000e+01', '2.00000000e+00', '3.00000000e+00',
       '4.00000000e+00', '5.00000000e+00', '6.00000000e+00',
       '7.00000000e+00', '8.00000000e+00', '9.00000000e+00',
       '1.00000000e+01', '1.10000000e+01', '1.20000000e+01',
       '1.30000000e+01', '1.40000000e+01', '1.50000000e+01',
       '1.60000000e+01', '1.70000000e+01', '1.80000000e+01'], 
      dtype='|S14')
>>>
```

So may be the solution would consist in converting the string numpy array `table2` to a float numpy array:

```
>>> table3 = table2.astype(np.float)
```

However, that is not the result you expect:

```
>>> table3
array([ 10.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
        12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.])
>>>
```

## First approach:

So may be you the only solution that remains would be the use of Python regex [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> begueradj = "['1.00000000e+01']"
>>> print begueradj
['1.00000000e+01']
>>> begueradj = re.sub("[\['\]]","",begueradj)
>>> print begueradj
1.00000000e+01
>>>
```

Thus, you can can program a method that loops on each value of `table2[i,:]` to remove away those undesired characters as shown in the example above.

## Second approach:

However, why to add more code with a regex method whereas you can resolve your problem in a less complicated way by a small modification to your `LoadTable()` method?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 16 13:07:36 2016

@author: Bill BEGUERADJ
"""    
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import numpy as np


class App(Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateUI()
        self.LoadTable()
        self.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
        parent.title("Bill Begueradj Python ttk.Treeview Demo Solution")
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def CreateUI(self):
        tv = Treeview(self)
        tv['columns'] = ('Parameter A', 'Parameter m', 'Parameter n')
        tv.heading("#0", text='Based on fit', anchor='c')
        tv.column("#0", anchor="c")
        tv.heading('Parameter A', text='Parameter A')
        tv.column('Parameter A', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.heading('Parameter m', text='Parameter m')
        tv.column('Parameter m', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.heading('Parameter n', text='Parameter n')
        tv.column('Parameter n', anchor='center', width=100)
        tv.grid(sticky = (N,S,W,E))
        self.treeview = tv
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def LoadTable(self):
        table1=np.reshape(np.array([10.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.,13.,14.,15.,16.,17.,18.]), (6,3))
        table2 = np.array(["%.8e" % w for w in table1.reshape(table1.size)])
        table2 = table2.reshape(table1.shape)


        for i in range(6):
           self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="based_on_line_"+str(i), values=(table2[i,0], table2[i,1],table2[i,2]))   
           # print table2[i,:]


def main():
    root = Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Demo:

The above program outputs this demo of what you are looking for:

[image]

**Notes:**

I coded this using Python 2.7, so if you want to use Python 3.x instead, then you have only two imports to adjust:

- `from tkinter import *` instead of  `from Tkinter import *`
- `from tkinter.ttk import *` instead of `from ttk import *`