# ValueError: too many values to unpack Tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, listbox

When writing a simple program to output the values and keys in a dictionary to a listbox in python using Tkinter I get the following error:

```
    for key, value in mydict.itervalues():
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Please see my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter as tk


mydict = {"0x00063":"6F 7D 9E 0E FF FF FF FF", 
          "0x00061":"FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF", 
          "0x00062":"AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA", 
          "0x00064":"00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"}

guiMain = tk.Tk()
recvDisplay = tk.Listbox(guiMain)

for key, value in mydict.itervalues():
    recvDisplay.insert(key, value)

recvButton = tk.Button(guiMain, text="Start Receive")
tranDisplay = tk.Listbox(guiMain)
tranButton = tk.Button(guiMain, text="Start Transmit")
recvDisplay.pack()
recvButton.pack()
tranDisplay.pack()
tranButton.pack()
guiMain.mainloop()
```

I need to be able to output the values and keys within to dictionary to the listbox `recvDisplay`, but I need the listbox to automatically refresh so it displays any changes to the dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mydict.itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) is an iterator over the values in `mydict`. If you want both the keys and the values, use  [`mydict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems):

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    recvDisplay.insert(tk.END, '{}, {}'.format(key, value))
```

Note: A Listbox only has one column. If you want multiple columns to display the key and value separately, you will need a different widget, such as a [treectrl.MultiListbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286093/190597), or put two `Listboxes` side-by-side.

Comment: That's almost it, but only the values are output not the keys, is this because you cannot output two variables to the same line in a listbox?

Answer (score 1):

1. `itervalues()`: Return an iterator over the dictionary’s values.

e.g.

```
>>> d = {"a":1, "b":2}
>>> d.itervalues()
<dictionary-valueiterator object at 0xb7201144>
>>> for i in d.itervalues():
...   print i, type(i)
... 
1 <type 'int'>
2 <type 'int'>
>>>
```

1. `items()`: Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs.
2. List item

e.g.

```
>>> d.items()
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

3. `iteritems()`: Return an iterator over the dictionary’s (key, value) pairs.

e.g.

```
>>> for i, j in d.iteritems():
...   i , j
... 
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
>>>
```

[more details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)