# Create listbox inside of a popup menu tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I've been using code from pythonprograming.net here's a link to the page. https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-main-menu-tkinter/

I'm trying to create a listbox that shows up when you click on a button from the menubar. I have code for a basic listbox that I got from here.  [Display Listbox with columns using Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286093/display-listbox-with-columns-using-tkinter)

My question is how can I populate my listbox using the generic code found from the second link?

This is my code so far:

```
def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Save Settings")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
def ParameterSelectionmsg(Treeview):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Parameter Selection")
    label = ttk.Listbox(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()
    popup.mainloop()
```

I want to build the listbox inside of this ParameterSelection popup menu using treeview.

```
class MyTkinter(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="clienticon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "My Tkinter")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save settings", command = lambda: popupmsg("IDK how to do this!"))
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: popupmsg("IDK how to do this!"))
        filemenu.add_command(label="Add", command = lambda: popupmsg("Add Parameter"))
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)


        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Save settings", command = lambda: popupmsg("IDK how to do this!"))
        editmenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: popupmsg("IDK how to do this!"))
        editmenu.add_command(label="Add", command = lambda: popupmsg("Add Parameter"))
        editmenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        parameter = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)
        parameter.add_command(label="Selection", command = lambda: popupmsg("This should contain the list of parameters"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Parameter", menu=parameter)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame(StartPage)
def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
    button1.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()

    #Graph Code
    plt.style.use("dark_background")
    x = (g[0].time[:111358])
    y = (g[0].data.f[:111358])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': x, 'Data': y})
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('ParmName', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize=12)
    plt.grid(linestyle = 'dashed')


    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)



app = MyTkinter()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think there are any popup list box options in tkinter but you could create one using the `toplevel` window and create your own pop up

Comment: There are lots of code here to go through really but the first thing pops up as an error is, you are creating more than one `Tk()` instance. Don't do that. If you want additional windows(like pop up etc.) use `Toplevel()`.