# How to get tkinter to print output from if statement in the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

i have button1 that runs a function which gets data and runs some calculations to add few columns to the data frame. this work when i press the button, but i don't know how to display the output of an if statement. should i create another button or lable or message box?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def onclick1():
    !pip install yfinance 
    .......
    data = yf.download('^GSPC','1927-12-30',date.today()) 

    def ROC(df, n):  
........
    data['STDEV_Dist_Frm_Mean'] = (data['Adj Close'] - data['Adj Close'].rolling(20).mean())/data['Adj Close']
    ....... 
    
    
    if data['BB_Width_PC'].tail(1).item() > 0.16:
        print('BB_Width_PC is > .16')
    elif data['BB_Width_PC'].tail(1).item() > 0.3:
        print('BB_Width_PC is > .3')
    .....
    else:
        print('No Significant Criteria Met')

root=tk.Tk()
button1=tk.Button(root, text="GetData", command=onclick1)
button2=tk.Button(root,text="na",command=output)
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's completely up to you. But I suggest you to also have a look at  `ListBox`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286093/display-listbox-with-columns-using-tkinter

Comment: sorry the question wasn't clear, I don't know how to do it. I tried putting the if statement in a function and assigning it to a button but didn't work. can you show me how to do it?

Comment: update your question with sample data and the operations that are being performed on the data.